# How to save results in R as a list and using them for further calculations?

Tags: r

I am new to R and wanted to ask a basic question. I have a time series for which I calculated ARIMA using the following code:

```
#ARIMA Model Script
library(tseries)

tui <- read.csv("C:/Data.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")

tsData <- ts(data = tui[,3], frequency = 12) #converting into time series for 3rd time time series column

tsData.arima101 <- auto.arima(tsData) #automatic selection of best ARIMA model
tsData.arima101 # Results of the ARIMA model
```

Now, I got some result from auto.arima which is fine but I want to use its intercept and other important statistics somewhere else. Can I refer to it in some way ? For example, I get the following result:

```
Call:
arima(x = d.tsData, order = c(2, 0, 3))

Coefficients:
      ar1     ar2      ma1      ma2     ma3  intercept
  -0.4415  0.3401  -0.3630  -0.9994  0.3625    -0.6277
s.e.1.0198  0.8519   1.0238   0.1836  1.0126     0.5106

sigma^2 estimated as 754.2:  log likelihood = -167.95,  aic = 349.91
```

Now I want to use AIC, AR, MA and intercept terms at some other point in the code but I do not know how to use it. I really need your help and Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `c(tsData.arima101)` will show you how everything is referenced in `tsData.arima101`. Then use `tsData.arima101$<ref>` to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
tsData <- ts(data = rnorm(12), frequency = 12) 

arima101 <- auto.arima(tsData)
```

Here the main model results:

```
> arima101
Series: tsData 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1  intercept
      -0.7112    -0.5140
s.e.   0.2635     0.1287

sigma^2 estimated as 0.5255:  log likelihood=-13.52
AIC=33.04   AICc=36.04   BIC=34.49
```

When you look at the structure of the object (`str(arima101)`), you see the elements that you can reference. The following is a bit more convenient to display:

```
names(arima101)
 [1] "coef"      "sigma2"    "var.coef"  "mask"      "loglik"   
 [6] "aic"       "arma"      "residuals" "call"      "series"   
[11] "code"      "n.cond"    "nobs"      "model"     "bic"      
[16] "aicc"      "x"
```

Now you can reference these elements the same way you would reference a list.

```
arima101$coef
       ar1  intercept 
-0.7112331 -0.5140006 

arima101$aic
[1] 33.03931
```

Since it is like accessing list elements, double brackets also work:

```
arima101[["coef"]]
       ar1  intercept 
-0.7112331 -0.5140006
```

If you want to put the results of your model or of various models into a dataframe, `broom` might be useful.

```
library(broom)
tidy(arima101, conf.int = T)
       term   estimate std.error   conf.low  conf.high
1       ar1 -0.7112331 0.2635398 -1.2277617 -0.1947046
2 intercept -0.5140006 0.1287007 -0.7662494 -0.2617519
```

Here, the output of `tidy(arima101)` is a dataframe. The relevant summary statistics can get accessed with `glance`:

```
glance(arima101)
      sigma    logLik      AIC      BIC
1 0.7249358 -13.51966 33.03931 34.49403
```

The output of these functions is always a dataframe, so that you can access them in the same way you would access your data. See `vignette("broom")` for more information.

Comment: Thanks ... it worked but now if I go through arima101$coef, I get all the list of cofficients but what If I want a particular coefficient for example ar1. So I tried tsData.arima101$coef$ar1 but it did not work. Any ideas for that. Thanks a lot

Comment: This works in the same way as if you are subsetting a vector, which in fact you do.  Try e.g. arima101$coef[1].

Comment: To be more general and maybe more pedagogical, you can look at the output of str or class(your.object), which tells you what type the object is. Then the question becomes "how to subset a -insert type here-", which you can easily google.